# fill a freehand drawing with opacity

Tags: drawing, fabricjs, opacity, fill

I have a simple fuction which fills the drawn image if the user chooses to

```
canvas.on('mouse:up', function() { 
                if(main.mode == 'fill') {
                  var object = main.canvas.item(main.canvas.getObjects().length-1);
                  object.fill = main.pColor();  
                  canvas.renderAll();
                }
            })
```

this works fine for solid(opacity 1) colors.  When using a color with less opacity:

[image]

It seems the stoke and fill overlap yielding a darker line.

I experimented with globalCompositeOperation.  I am thinking eliminate the stroke or set the stroke opacity to zero. I hope there is a better answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a few approaches: setting stroke opacity to zero and trying to get rid of the stroke altogether.

what works best is adding

```
object.set('strokeWidth', 0);
```

to the handler above.

set ensures the canvas will be updated.

It is working well.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).